# Query occasionally reports error "OutOfRange"

Tags: cnosdb

Query occasionally reports error "OutOfRange"
version:cnosdb 2.3.2, revision = aefb72c4acb4fb4e3613a744eb3166a83961630b
I have tried many times here, and this kind of error will occasionally appear. Sometimes it takes a long 30s to find out, but sometimes it is also very fast.

```
cnosdb_admin_stats ❯ select * from syslog order by time limit 10;
422 Unprocessable Entity, details: {"error_code":"020000","error_message":"Network: status: OutOfRange, message: \"Error, message length too large: found 4541853 bytes, the limit is: 4194304 bytes\", details: [], metadata: MetadataMap { headers: {} }"}

Stack backtrace:
   0: anyhow::error::<impl anyhow::Error>::msg
   1: anyhow::__private::format_err
   2: client::ctx::SessionContext::sql::{{closure}}
   3: client::exec::exec_and_print::{{closure}}
   4: client::exec::exec_from_repl::{{closure}}
   5: cnosdb_cli::main::{{closure}}
   6: cnosdb_cli::main
   7: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
   8: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
   9: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
  10: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  11: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  12: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  13: std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
  14: std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:487:40
  15: std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panicking.rs:451:19
  16: std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
  17: std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/39f2657d1101b50f9b71ae460b762d330cc8426b/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  18: main
  19: __libc_start_main
  20: <unknown>
cnosdb_admin_stats ❯ select * from syslog order by time limit 10;
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| time                          | host         | node | path                                                        | loglevel | message                                                                              | module                     |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112003328 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | ERROR    | Failed to get disk info '/var/lib/cnosdb/db': No such file or directory (os error 2) | meta::model::meta_admin    |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112142243 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | WAL '1' starts write                                                                 | tskv::wal                  |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112283140 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | WARN     | Recover: reading wal from seq '0'                                                    | tskv::wal                  |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112355985 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Recover: reading wal '/var/lib/cnosdb/wal/_000001.wal' for seq 0 to 0                | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112406862 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Job 'WAL' starting.                                                                  | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112462240 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Flush task handler started                                                           | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112502017 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Summary task handler started                                                         | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112547768 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Job 'WAL' started.                                                                   | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112583328 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | CnosDB server start as query_tskv mode                                               | cnosdb                     |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112632517 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | http server start addr: 0.0.0.0:8902, bundle mode                                    | cnosdb::http::http_service |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
Query took 39.306 seconds.
cnosdb_admin_stats ❯ select * from syslog order by time limit 10;
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| time                          | host         | node | path                                                        | loglevel | message                                                                              | module                     |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112003328 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | ERROR    | Failed to get disk info '/var/lib/cnosdb/db': No such file or directory (os error 2) | meta::model::meta_admin    |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112142243 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | WAL '1' starts write                                                                 | tskv::wal                  |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112283140 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | WARN     | Recover: reading wal from seq '0'                                                    | tskv::wal                  |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112355985 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Recover: reading wal '/var/lib/cnosdb/wal/_000001.wal' for seq 0 to 0                | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112406862 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Job 'WAL' starting.                                                                  | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112462240 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Flush task handler started                                                           | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112502017 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Summary task handler started                                                         | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112547768 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | Job 'WAL' started.                                                                   | tskv::kvcore               |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112583328 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | CnosDB server start as query_tskv mode                                               | cnosdb                     |
| 2023-10-27T03:34:09.112632517 | 192.168.0.21 | 21   | /data1/DF_ENT_DS/query_tskv1/log/cnosdb/tsdb.log.2023-10-08 | INFO     | http server start addr: 0.0.0.0:8902, bundle mode                                    | cnosdb::http::http_service |
+-------------------------------+--------------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
Query took 38.763 seconds.
cnosdb_admin_stats ❯
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your config file for the size of the query request, and try to make that parameter larger

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the body limit of http requests, and the body returned by your request is too large.